# Как проиндексировать файлы в SourceTree&

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-commit, source-tree

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ряд файлов в репозитории, который отображаются вот так. Нажатие на "Индексировать всё" не приводит ни к какому результату. Часть файлов .txt, часть .py. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Во-первых, у сорс три бывает подглюкивает интерфейс, поэтому рекомендую просто закрыть программу и открыть заново. Во-вторых, если без мистических причин... то покажите .gitignore - ну мало ли что там.

Comment: перезапускать пробовал

Comment: .gitignore даже не создан

Comment: Имху, тогда вам в техподдержку ST с указанием версии ПО и ОС.

Comment: сомневаюсь, что я наткнулся на какую-то уникальную проблему, вроде ничего особенного не делаю

Comment: Возможно. Но я помню постоянно раздравший меня баг, когда пишешь текст коммита, а чекбокс "сразу запушить" не ставится. А после этого и кнопка "Отправить" зависала. Поэтому я до перехода на новый ST часто сидел в командной строке. Кстати, а если консоль открыть и дать команду `add -A`, то сработает?

Comment: да, но git commit что-то странное выдает